# Using repeatActionForever on SKSpriteNodes programmatically created with same name in a loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

For context, I'm making a brick-breaker game in iOS and want the bricks I create to all move to the left and right repeatedly as the ball bounces around the scene.

I have a method in my code that I call once when the scene is presented that adds a couple of rows of sprite nodes to the scene as bricks, as shown below

```
-(void) addBricks:(CGSize)size {    

    // add a new row of bricks
    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {

        // add top column of bricks
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {


            SKSpriteNode *brick = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"brick"];

            brick.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:brick.frame.size];
            brick.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
            brick.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = brickCategory;

            int xPos = ((brick.frame.size.width / 2) + 20) + ((brick.frame.size.width / 2) + 30) * i;
            int yPos = size.height - (30 * j);


            // generate the sequence that the brick will perform
            SKAction *moveHorizontal = [SKAction moveToX:xPos + 20 duration:1.0f];
            moveHorizontal.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;
            SKAction *moveBack = [moveHorizontal reversedAction];
            SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.4f];
            SKAction *backAndForth = [SKAction sequence:@[moveHorizontal, wait, moveBack, wait]];
            SKAction *repeatHorizMove = [SKAction repeatActionForever:backAndForth];


            brick.position = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos);

            // add the brick
            [self addChild:brick];

            // make it move back and forth
            [brick runAction:repeatHorizMove];
        }

    }
}
```

My problem is that, while all of the bricks will move to the right when the scene starts, they don't move back and repeat the action over and over like I want them to. I think it may have something to do with giving them all the same name when they are programmatically created, but I know the scene retains all of the bricks despite them having the same name.

How can I get it so that all of the SpriteNodes (bricks) that I create keep moving back and forth forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [moveToX action](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/moveToX%3aduration%3a) is not reversible. Always check the reference for comments like this.

This should fix it:

```
        SKAction *moveHorizontal = [SKAction moveToX:xPos + 20 duration:1.0f];
        moveHorizontal.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;
        SKAction *moveBack = [SKAction moveToX:xPos duration:1.0];
```